# How can I improve regression?

Tags: python, matlab, regression, svm, random-forest

I want to ask if there is any way to make the regression really generalized for my dataset.

My problem is that after I trained the data with Random forest or SVM regressor, it works kinda well in the training dataset but it shows very bad result when I try with test dataset.. even if they have the same underlying equations.

I really don't have idea how to improve this. Does it mean that I should keep training my regression with more dataset?

Could anybody help me? :(

Comment: Dear sasha, I recommend you to read https://stackoverflow.com/tour before asking another question.

Comment: If the suggestions so far is at least useful to you, we wouldn't mind an upvote either.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be better what kind of dataset you wanna train and test... e.g. dimension, # items, and so on.
There are several reasons but in case, usually the training fails when

1. the size of training set is small
2. domain space is to large to learn / quite non-convex / very non-linear
3. model parameters are not appropriate

This is just my thought, but as regressor, the SVM or other tree-based models like random forest / decision tree are kinda unstable when the size of a dataset is small. I recommend to use the Gaussian process regressor if the dimension size is less than 10.

And it's really recommended to normalize / regularize your dataset before trying to train / test any models.

FYI, below are the links I just googled.

- https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2015/01/29/six-quick-tips-improve-regression-modeling/
- https://www.jigsawacademy.com/5-super-tips-to-improve-your-linear-regression-models/

Answer (score 1):

We are not able to answer your question. You dont even try to provide data or your code. How could one tell why your problem appears.

Just my two cents:

1. Is the train and test data unbalanced?
   -> This is the main reason for bad test results
2. Is the sample reasonable large?

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I have dataset of dimension 4, one output and about 0.5 million observation. Can I say this is large? and what do you mean by unbalanced, can you please explain more? Thank you in advance!